# Relationship between Specific heat capacity and Electrical conductivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, conductors

I am an IB student going into senior year and I have an Extended Essay to complete. The research question I formulated was "How does Electrical Conductivity depend on specific heat capacity?" So I was wondering if anyone knew the answer to this before I begun experimenting because I'm going to have to purchase a power pack, voltmeter, ammeter, and materials to test on.

On a side note, if anyone is familiar with the IB Extended Essay, I'm a 17 year old car enthusiast (and I understand almost all the mechanics of cars), I play golf, I'm into technology (the hardware side, not so much the software side) and I'm looking into going into Mechanical Engineering with the end goal of being in Automotive Engineering. So if anyone has a good research question based on my background that I could change my current rq from that'd be of great help.

Thanks, 
Romit

Comment: You need to discuss your topic with your advisor / lecturer and make sure it is clear. Topics I could suggest may be outside of what you want or even have the material / equipment to test.

Comment: I did discuss this with him and he told me to go ahead and investigate it. I can't really discuss it with him now because he left the school and I won't know who his replacement is till school starts in September.

Comment: I think you need formulate a more specific question. You can find reputable tables (Kaye and Laby, etc) listing specific heat and electrical conductivity for hundreds of materials. That will answer your current question without measuring anything, but it probably isn't sufficient for an IB extended essay. If there is a relation, the interesting question is "why" but investigating that might be way beyond any experiment you can do with a budget of a few dollars, rather than a few thousand (or million) dollars.

Comment: Since you like golf and mechanical engineering, what about doing a project on the aerodynamics of golf balls or something similar? Your current question has the issue that electrical conductivity and specific heat are generally anti-correlated, and you could just look up everything in a table anyways.

Comment: The thing is, my current physics IA looks at the effect of the number of dimples golf balls have on a balls flight and air time. I have scrapped the original EE idea and am looking for something new.